# Position JS search box over and image and make transparent

Tags: javascript, forms

I would like to add a search box and make it transparent to a 80% degree and sit on the left or right of this image with padding http://www.holidays2crete.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/holiday-search-background.jpg.

I have tried following some of the examples on stackoverflow but managed to get nowhere.

```
<script src="http://scripts.distributenetwork.net/searchbox/searchbox_script_v3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div style="width:405px;height:235px;" id="dt_searchcontainer_top"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var text = '#000000';
var background = '#FFFFFF';
var border = '#ffffff';

var container_id = 'dt_searchcontainer_top';
var whitelabel_url = 'quickstart.travelresults.net';
var departureairport = 'LON';
var destination = '';
var destination_data = '';
var boardbasis = 'AI~FB~HB~BB~SC~RO~OtherBoardBasis';
var starrating = '5~4~3~2~Other';
var new_window = true;
var customVariableName = ['QSUserGUID','awin_id','affilinet_id','td_id','afuture_id','gan_id'];
var customVariableValue = ['eded668a-58f7-468d-a542-0efa301810d9','107649','464082','1686829','102616','610263'];
var searchbox_title = '';
var brandlist = 'AIR~ESS~TCH~TCF~MAN~LCH~OTB~BSK~EBK~LMN~NLS';

load_searchbox('type3', whitelabel_url, text, background, border,    container_id, departureairport, destination, destination_data, boardbasis, starrating, new_window, customVariableName, customVariableValue, searchbox_title, brandlist);
</script>
```

I also need to add it all into a wordpress page or to my front page.

Would anyone be kind enough to help me please :)